# SQL query to replace all cells with new data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database, managed by phpmyadmin. I have about 14,000 records - all pin codes for a script that users use to enter a contest.

I need to update the DB to reflect this years codes. I have been supplied the codes in an Excel file. There are several other columns (name, address etc) in the DB.

What I want to know is:

1. what to export the Excell File as
2. What SQL query will essentially replace the data  in table= contest column= pin with the new records from excel.

I have searched and can't seem to find any help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question might be a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the file as an Excel file into PHPMyAdmin using the import feature, and then to update the information you would use a similar query to this
`UPDATE contest,new_table SET contest.pin=new_table.pin WHERE contest.name = new_table.name`

The end part of the query will be where you set the link between the two tables so it knows which PIN corresponds with each person

Comment: Ok, I have the two pieces of data inserted into the main DB. Every time I run the query to merge them, PHPmyadmin times out. 

I am running the following: 'code'UPDATE contest,pin2 SET contest.pin=pin2.pin 

(I had to delete the 'WHERE' call, as I kept getting a syntax error)

In my DB 'admin' there is a table 'contest' with a column 'pin' and the other table is called 'pin2' and the row is called 'pin'

I'm not sure what syntax I'm missing. I need contest.pin to have the data from pin2.pin

Answer (score 0):

To update the data in a table you need to use this SQL syntax:

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <columnName> = <value> WHERE <condition>
```

When dealing with this sort of requirements, I usually add a column to the Excel and use the `=CONCATENATE()` function to get a bunch of UPDATE statements to execute

[image]